# Fluent Nhibernate - make References from children side only

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have `Survey` that `HasMany` `Question` that `HasMany` `Option`.
I want to create a reference from `Option` to `Survey`.
The problem is that Every time I want to create a `new Survey` with all of its children, I need to loop on all `survey.Questions` and loop on all `survey.Questions.Options` and set o each `Option` the `Survey` (or else Nhibernate will create a `new Survey` for each `Option`)
** I dont want to have `IList<Option>` on Survey if I do that it will solve the problem but it would be heavy and unusable **

```
public class SurveyMap : ClassMap<Survey>
    {
        public SurveyMap()
        {
           Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            HasMany(x => x.Questions).KeyColumn("SurveyId").Inverse().AsBag().Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }

    public class QuestionMap : ClassMap<Question>
    {
        public QuestionMap()
        {
           Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            HasMany(x => x.Options).KeyColumn("QuestionId").Inverse().AsBag().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }

    public class OptionMap : ClassMap<Option>
    {
        public OptionMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            References(x => x.Survey).Column("SurveyId").Cascade.All();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need the reference to survey on option? Why not backreference Question which backreferences Survey? you already defined inverse on the collection mappings so i assume you already have the backreferences

Comment: @Firo - I am adding this reference to minimize join queries for other usages. like external reporting system. Since `Survey` contains `IList<Question>` it means that question is mapped to `Survey`, so question is mapped to `Survey`, but I want Option to have that connection as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to separate your reporting concerns from your applications business logic concerns. Use the mappings that you already have for your applications business logic, and  provide a different interface into the data for your reporting requirements. You could use either HQL, SQL or new objects and maps for this.